# Add an ArrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java, file, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am having a problem with adding new elements to an `ArrayList` , I will show you my problem :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr1= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> arr2= new ArrayList<String>();
```

So I am adding new elements from a text file , spliting it line by line , then word by word , example :
we suppose my text file contains :

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

What I need is to put each word in **arr2** , then i put **arr2** into **arr1** with the following code :

```
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split("\\,");
            if (arr2.isEmpty()) {
                for (int ae = 0; ae < words.length; ae++) {
                    arr2.add(ae, words[ae]);
                }
                arr1.add(arr2);
            } else {
                for (int ae = 0; ae < words.length; ae++) {
                    arr2.set(ae, words[ae]);
                }
                arr1.add(arr2);                    
            }
        }
        file.close();
```

So what I need is :`[[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]]`
but I get : `[[i,j,k,l],[i,j,k,l],[i,j,k,l]]`

Any solution please?!

Comment: You are adding same list (arr2) 3 times. You need to fill and add *separate* (new) lists, not re-*set* same one.

Comment: you should create a new `ArrayList<String> arr2= new ArrayList<String>();` every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `java` it deals with references, So you have to create new `arr2` every time you read the line because when you add `arr2` to `arr1` it still hold the reference of `arr2` too, So every change you are making on arr2 affects arrays inside arr1 + the array arr2 that is going to be added to arr1 (They are all the same array).

A kind of solution is to declare arr2 inside the while loop like this
`ArrayList<String> arr2= new ArrayList<String>();` as @dehasi said in the comments,

```
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> arr2= new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] words = line.split("\\,");
        for (int ae = 0; ae < words.length; ae++) {
            arr2.add(words[ae]);
        }
        arr1.add(arr2);

    }
    file.close();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks bro! this is so helpful ! it works